# How to make video player fullscreen on button click using or javascript in all major mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

i have made a custom player. its working fine except one thing. it is not getting full screen in android or blackberry default browser.
is it possible to make video player fullscreen with same function.?
right now i am using

The events  are: webkitbeginfullscreen and webkitendfullscreen i'm working on

```
var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
player.addEventListener('webkitbeginfullscreen', onVideoBeginsFullScreen, false);
player.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', onVideoEndsFullScreen, false);
```

but these are not working in android or blackberry.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("button").click(function () {
   launchFullScreen(document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]);
})

// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Reference: http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen

Comment: essentially this should be the answer the only caveat is that some browsers might still require the browser engine prefix like webkit, moz, ms: eg: webkitRequestFullscreen or webkitRequestFullScreen (yep capital and lowercase Screen)

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato check now :) Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [screenfull wrapper](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js)

Using it is as simple as

```
var elem = document.getElementById('target');
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (screenfull.enabled) {
        screenfull.request(elem);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also use this plugin, it takes care of the cross browser annoyances.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("video");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```